# Cannot add Foreign Key on tables in DashDB / DB2 on Bluemix

Tags: db2, foreign-keys, ibm-cloud, dashdb

When I create a table in DashDB (DB2) on Bluemix like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    depname CHAR (10) UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    phone   INTEGER
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( depname ) ;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    "EmpNr"          NUMERIC (3) UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    empname         CHAR (20) ,
    depname         CHAR (10) ,
    EMPLOYEE2_title CHAR (20)
  );
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY ( "EmpNr" ) ;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (depname ) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ( depname ) ;
```

Bluemix disallows adding a Foreign Key constraint for this table type.

Answer (score 5):

When you look at the [documentation for dashDB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011049.html?lang=en) (not DB2) you will notice that foreign keys can be created. However, a table by default is created column-organized. Only non-enforced referential constraints are supported. In your example you would need to add NOT ENFORCED to your statement:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
 ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (depname ) 
 REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ( depname ) NOT ENFORCED;
```

Answer (score 2):

By default on CREATE a DashDB table on Bluemix is 'organized by column'...
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0060592.html

This will also disallow adding Foreign Key constraints for this table type.

To add FKs add `ORGANIZE BY ROW` to your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
    depname CHAR (10) UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    phone   INTEGER
  ) ORGANIZE BY ROW;

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT 
 ADD CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( depname ) ;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    "EmpNr"          NUMERIC (3) UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
    empname         CHAR (20) ,
    depname         CHAR (10) ,
    EMPLOYEE2_title CHAR (20)
  ) ORGANIZE BY ROW;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
 ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY ( "EmpNr" ) ;

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
 ADD CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (depname )
 REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ( depname ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this if my tables are getting created by JPA?