# Why does Bluemix dashDB operation throws a SqlSyntaxErrorException with SQLCODE=-1667?

Tags: java, database, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm getting this error even though I am not trying to edit the table/column:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the type of the specified table.  Specified table: "DASH103985.wajihs".  Table type: "ORGANIZE BY COLUMN".  Operation: "WITH RS".. SQLCODE=-1667, SQLSTATE=42858

```
@MultipartConfig
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DemoServlet.class.getName());
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Resource(lookup="jdbc/db2")DataSource dataSource;

private String getDefaultText() {
  TweetsCombined = new String(" ");
  try {
    // Connect to the Database
    Connection con = null;
    try {
      System.out.println("Connecting to the database");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      TweetsCombined = "first" +e;
    }

    // Try out some dynamic SQL Statements
    Statement stmt = null;

  try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "wajihs";// change table name here to one
                  // chosen in the first website
    String columnName = "msgBody";// msgBody is where the tweets
                                          // are stored
    String query = "SELECT * FROM \"" + tableName + "\"";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
      content = rs.getString(columnName) + ". ";
      if (content.toLowerCase().contains("RT".toLowerCase())
              || content.toLowerCase().contains("Repost: ".toLowerCase())) {
        // do nothing
      }
      else {
        TweetsCombined.concat(content);
      }

    }
    // Close everything off
    // Close the Statement
    stmt.close();
    // close
    con.commit();
    // Close the connection
    con.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    TweetsCombined = "second" +e;
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  TweetsCombined = "third" + e;
  System.out.println(e);
}
return TweetsCombined;
```

}

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation for the SQLCODE and SQLSTATE values? Can you tell us where in that source file the exception is triggered? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628657/cannot-add-foreign-key-on-tables-in-dashdb-db2-on-bluemix/31628658#31628658), dashDB, with its BLU Acceleration features, has certain limitations compared to DB2 without BLU Acceleration. In your case it is that you can only run queries with the CS isolation level against column-organized tables.

Either change your connection configuration to use CS isolation level or create your table(s) while explicitly specifying `ORGANIZE BY ROW`.

Comment: Thanks mustaccio, your explanation saved my day!